# Using the compound pipe %<>% from magrittr doesn't appear to be assigning correctly

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I seem to have some issue with using the %<>% pipe.

Per the magrittr documentation

> The compound assignment pipe-operator, %<>%, is used to update a value
> by first piping it into one or more rhs expressions, and then
> assigning the result. For example, some_object %<>% foo %>% bar is
> equivalent to some_object <- some_object %>% foo %>% bar. It must be
> the first pipe-operator in a chain, but otherwise it works like %>%.

However, I am seeing behavior that contradicts this. Here's my counterexample (apologies that it's directly from my code)

```
Temp$IncurralAge <- Temp$IncurralAge %>% round((.-2)/5)*5
```

Works perfectly.

```
Temp$IncurralAge %<>% round((.-2)/5)*5
```

Instead prints identical output to if I did

```
Temp$IncurralAge %>% round((.-2)/5)*5
```

I don't see what's going wrong here, anyone see any problems with my syntax?

Comment: Please read/follow the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tg page.  In particular, please provide complete reproducible input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the expressions shown in the question work the way that the question seems to believe.

**R Expression Precedence**

`%...%` has a higher precedence than `*` so `*` is performed AFTER `%>%` is performed so the multiplication of 5 is not part of the right hand side of %>% but rather the result of `x %>% round(...)` is multiplied by 5 in a last step. See `?Syntax` for the precedence table.

For example below `y` is set to its square root, not to twice its square root, because `y %<>% sqrt` is done first since `%<>%` has higher precedence than `*` and the multiplication is done only after the assignment is done.

```
y <- 1:3
y %<>% sqrt * 2
y
```

**Using Dot**

Also dot must be an argument to the function that is passed on the RHS if it is desired to avoid having it automatically inserted as the first argument -- if the dot is just part of an expression that is one of its arguments that does not count -- dot will still be inserted.

For example,

```
10 %>% sum(.+2)
## [1] 22

10 %>% sum(., .+2) # same
```

**Using %>%**

In all the cases below `x` or equivalently `.` is the first argument of `round` and the second argument is the expression containing `x` or dot.  The multiplication by 5 is done on the output of `x %>% round(...)`

```
x <- 1:10 # assumed input

# these are all equivalent

x %>% round((.-2)/5)*5

round(x, (x-2)/5)*5

x %>% round(., (.-2)/5)*5

x %>% round((.-2)/5)*5

(x %>% round(., (.-2)/5)) * 5
```

Presumably what is wanted is one of these equivalent expressions:

```
round((x-2)/5) * 5

x %>% `-`(2) %>% `/`(5) %>% round %>% `*`(5)

x %>% subtract(2) %>% divide_by(5) %>% round %>% multiply_by(5)

x %>% { round((.-2)/5) * 5 }
```

**Using %<>%**

The last two lines of code above also work with `%<>%` in place of `%>%`, e.g.

```
x %<>% { round((.-2)/5) * 5 }
```

Comment: Right on, that was exactly the answer. Thank you very very much.